# Inter-rater reliability simultaneously on multiple binary data

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics

I have drug prescription records on 5 different drugs (A,B,C,D,E) on 2 different time points over a bunch of patients. 1/0 stands for use or not-use the specific drug, respectively.

My questions are, 
If I want to estimate the inter-rater reliability of 2 different time points simultaneously on 5 different drugs at same time, what test should I apply?

Should I separately calculate the kappa on each drug and reported them individually ? or Could I just average the kappa score (geometric or arithmetic mean?)??

Thank you ~

Comment: Are the drugs mutually-exclusive or could a patient have more than one at a time?

Comment: I'm not quit understanding the meaning of mutually-exclusive here....

It is possible for each patient to receive more than one drug at a time. 
However, patient would have only 1 combination of drugs (A,B,C,D,E) at one time: 
e.g. patient would  be prescribed drug A,D and E at time 1. Coding as  (A,B,C,D,E)=(1,0,0,1,1) .

Answer (score 1):

Because your categories are not mutually-exclusive (i.e., it is possible for each patient to receive more than one drug at a time), it would be most appropriate to calculate agreement (or kappa, pi, etc.) for each drug separately. Another option. albeit a less commonly used and more complex one, would be to use the approach of Kraemer (1980) setting all drugs as tied for first. [See my answer here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144874/how-to-calculate-inter-rater-reliability-with-multiple-raters-and-multiple-categ/207257#207257)